# fetch invited contact details from outlook appointment with c#

Tags: c#, outlook, automation

I develop VB.net 2008 with C# Application for fetch appointment item from outlook 2003.
I need to show the contact with their mobile number, which are stored in outlook contact
related to the appointments in calender.

```
int i = 0;
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
oNS.Logon(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, true);
Outlook.MAPIFolder Ocalender = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
Outlook.Items oItems = Ocalender.Items ;
int iNumContacts = oItems.Count;
Outlook.AppointmentItem c = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)(oItems[1]);

string sub = c.Subject;
string body = c.Body;
```

If someone need more description about this,kindly ask

Comment: Do you need to support multiple address books and global address lists or just the default address book?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just grab them from the contact item.
Retrieve the contacts by searching for them via Find ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220350.aspx)):

```
string filter =
      "[EMail1Address] = " + address + 
  " OR [EMail2Address] = " + address + 
  " OR [EMail3Address] = " + address;
ContactItem ci = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items.Find(filter);
```

You can get the addresses from the recipient items stored with the appointment.